# Expected number of switched lights

Tags: probability, markov-chains

This problem has been bugging me for a bit, can't find a way to make progress.

I have $n$ lights in a row, all initially turned off, and I would like some specific $k$ positions to be turned on. Without loss of generality, let us say that I would like the first $k$ of them to be turned on.

If I switch the lights from on to off (or vice versa) randomly, what is the expected number of switches it will take to reach my desired configuration?

If I turn one of the first $k$ lights off (after it's already been turned on), I am required to need at least $1$ extra switch to get it to the correct configuration. Same goes for turning the last $n-k$ lights on; they require another switch to turn them off.

Not sure how to tackle this problem. At first I wrote something like:

$$E(x) = \frac{k}{n}(E(x) - 1) + \frac{n-k}{n}(E(x) + 1)$$

Obviously this is wrong, but the idea was on the first turn, if you turn  one of the first $k$ lights on you've made one "switch" worth of progress toward your goal, but if you turn one of the last $n-k$ lights on, you're required to at least make one more switch to eventually win. I've used this sort of technique for these sort of "recurrence"-esque probability problems, so I'm wondering if I can extend that to this problem.

The other thing I considered was using Markov chains, but I'm also not sure how to set up the state transition matrix. My guess is there's $k(n-k)$ states since we only care about the number of "on" lights in the first $k$ and the number of "on" lights in the last $n-k$.

Is there an easier way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you only care about the number of lights that are currently in the desired state. So you start out in the state $n-k$, and you want to reach the state $n$. The recurrence is

$$
E_j=1+\frac jnE_{j-1}+\frac{n-j}nE_{j+1}\;.
$$

The initial values are $E_n=0$ and $E_{n-1}=2^n-1$ (where the latter is due to the fact that starting from $E_n$ the expected return time is the number of states, $2^n$). I don't see how to derive a closed form, but for given values of $k$ and $n$ you can use the recurrence and the initial values to derive the desired $E_{n-k}$.

Comment: So you get  $E_{j+1}=\dfrac{n(E_j-1)-j E_{j-1}}{n-j}$.    It seems $E_n = n \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{2^i}{i+1}$ related to [OEIS A126674](https://oeis.org/A126674)

Comment: @Henry: I don't understand. In my notation, $E_n=0$. What does $E_n$ denote in your expression?

Comment: joriki: My second expression should probably have been for what you call $E_0$  rather than $E_n$ (i.e. zero correct and $n$ incorrect).  This also seems to be $2^{n-1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{n-1 \choose i}$